# node visibility only selected users from a list?

Tags: organic-groups, users

**PROJECT**
I am creating a 'web portal' with Drupal 7:
Each registered user is a admin of a your group. (organic groups)
This admin-user may invite other users to your group.
All users of Group can create Nodes.
**I WOULD LIKE:**
I would like this nodes are not visible to all group's users, but I want that who create the node can select (from a list of all users in the group!) the users who can see this specific node.

Can anyone recommend a way?
...or advise me some modules?

Thanks!